# How to hide cells with too small n in gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to replace estimates with a sample size smaller than 30 with "~" in my table. I tried using the modify_table_body function and this works, but only for small numbers. If *n* has 3 or more digits my solution stops working.
I made a reproducible example to make my problem more clear.

```
set.seed(2023)
trt <- sample(c("Drug A", "Drug B"), 1340, replace = T)
grade <- sample(c("I", "II", "III"), 1340, replace = T)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(trt, grade))

ex1 <- dat %>%
  select(grade, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt,
              statistic = ~"{n}",
              percent = "row") %>% modify_table_body(~ .x %>% 
dplyr::mutate(stat_1 = ifelse(stat_2 < 30, "~", stat_1)))
```

[image: ex1]

```
ex2 <- dat %>%
  select(grade, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt,
              statistic = ~"{n}",
              percent = "row") %>% modify_table_body(~ .x %>% 
dplyr::mutate(stat_1 = ifelse(stat_2 < 20, "~", stat_1)))
```

[image: ex2]

Obviously, ex1 is false, but I don't know why this happens. R apparently thinks three digit numbers starting with 2 are smaller than 30.

If you know what is wrong or have a different approach that lets me avoid this problem, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your values are characters, so you should convert them to numeric to use the `ifelse` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
set.seed(2023)
trt <- sample(c("Drug A", "Drug B"), 1340, replace = T)
grade <- sample(c("I", "II", "III"), 1340, replace = T)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(trt, grade))

dat %>%
  select(grade, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt,
              statistic = ~"{n}",
              percent = "row") %>% 
  modify_table_body(~ .x %>% 
                      dplyr::mutate(stat_1 = ifelse(as.numeric(stat_2) < 30, "~", stat_1)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, what an easy solution!